# Can you run a suite of suites but exclude certain tests from running?

Tags: testing, testng

Is there any way to specify I would like to run a suite of suites but on a particular suite exclude specified tests?

```
<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" /> <!-- exclude TestX and TestY -->
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Comment: what are you trying to run this with?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand the question. The TestNG dependency I'm running with is 6.9.6.